# Getting External Data to Shopify via AJAX, JSON, jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, shopify

How can I tell my website to go to a URI, grab the data off of that website, bring it back, and auto update my websites information?

I am solely trying to understand the best practices for these types of requests and what the structure would look like before any coding starts.

Some of my knowledge:

I have found out that this can be accomplished via AJAX, but what is your recommendation?

Comment: ajax (or some form of http communication between the client and the 3rd party website) is pretty much the only option, aside from having your server send that http request. Note that if using XHR (the transport usually used by ajax) you'll have to follow the Same Origin Policy, meaning the 3rd party website would need to supply proper CORS headers for clients browsing your website to be able to get that data.

Comment: @KevinB Shopify's language is Ruby, but includes languages like PHP. The only thing that may be a problem is, I don't think I have access to their servers to write PHP there.  In theory, would that be correct? I could write PHP for a server and that server would do a GET function for the data, and then store it inside of the database?

Comment: yes, that is possible and would avoid having to deal with the same origin policy.

Comment: @KevinB awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can only save data to shopify database using its API and to use them you need to make an app and to get the data from app, you need to add the URL in app proxy. see screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66Ry.png)